# Localization. Use React or Spring Boot?

Tags: reactjs, spring, localization

I am new to Web Development and I am currently writing my first web app. I am trying to implement localization and I am not sure what option I should use. I am using both spring boot and react. With spring I could use LocaleResolver and thymeleaf. And with React I could use the i18next package. So I am asking myself with would make more sense to use and why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: React.

Long answer:

If you are using React, probably you are not using `thymeleaf`. In other words, you will probably create a big Javascript package which displays the UI, and the Spring backend will do nothing but providing some *raw data*.

For example, say you are building a blog. Your Spring may do something like -

- if someone asks me at url `mydomain.com/posts/42`, I will return him `{"title": "Hello", "author": "Tom"}`

And your React will do something like -

- when I am initializing, I should ask the server about the content of this blog post with id=42. Thus I should make a http query `fetch('mydomain.com/posts/42')`
- then I see data from my server. I got `{"title": "Hello", "author": "Tom"}`.
- now I should render it to the screen so the users can see it. For example, it will be rendered as `<h1>TITLE: Hello</h1> <p>AUTHOR: Tom</p>`.

Now you see that, your UI goes within the frontend. Thus it is reasonable to do localization with your UI.